# Depth first Search graph from pandas frame?

Tags: python, graph, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a data frame as below which is df, the values between the index in columns and rows are weights.

`A   B   B   C
B  1   11  ... ..
C  11  2   ..  ..
D  10  10`

I use this code below for creating graph:
`G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values.astype(int))`

when I call `G2[5]` for example
the result is here `{26: {'weight': 1019}, 39: {'weight': 256}, 59: {'weight': 248}}`

And then use this for Depth first search

```
def dfs(graph, start, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(start)
    for next in graph[start] - visited:
        dfs(graph, next, visited)
    return visited
```

But I got the error `unhashable type: 'dict'` when I called the function with graph G above and start point is G[5] for example `dfs(G, G[5])`. Anyone know the reason why because the dfs function work with other graph?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. [ask]

Comment: How are u calling `dfs`? What is  `graph` and `start`? Is `visited` provided? How could be help you if you dont care to provide sufficient information.

Comment: I edited the question, thank you.